# Wordpress Widget Control Panel

Tags: widget, wordpress

I'm a little confused with regards to Wordpress widgets, but only slightly. I have a fully functional widget and Ive set to display all the relevant data I want it to, however I wanted to add some additional functionality to it via the widget control panel.

When you drag a widget to an active location in the Wordpress admin area certain plugins allow you to make some additional changes to them there, setting certain features... This is what I want to do...

However I am unsure how I'm supposed to actual get my form into that area, can anyone shed any light onto this for me?

Thanks in advance for any and all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it once again. for anyone else having problems the answer is:

wp_register_widget_control():

Syntax is:

```
wp_register_widget_control( int|string $id, string $name, callable $control_callback, array $options = array() )
```

Registers widget control callback for customizing options.

`wp_register_widget_control()` is located in `wp-includes/widgets.php`

For More Information Refer:
[wp_register_widget_control](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_widget_control)